# Android - BroadcastReceivers registered inside Service do not work

Tags: java, android, service, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an Android application, which uses Bluetooth to connect to a remote device (specifically HC-05 Bluetooth module). Currently I'm struggling with registering a few `BroadcastReceiver` inside a `Service` class properly.

What I want to achieve is:

1. In `MainActivity` there is a `Button` with `onClickListener`, which launches the `ConnectionService`.
2. In `onStartCommand` method of the instantiated service I register the receivers previously created (as fields in the service class).
3. When a Bluetooth device is found, I want to execute some code. The code should be included in `onReceive` method of the receiver, which is set to listen for `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND`.
   [I know, this is not something really complex...]

BUT:
When I register the receivers and start discovery, it seems that the receivers are not working. I mean, they do not receive actions.

**My code looks like this:**

In MainActivity:

```java
connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(Constants.TAG,"CONNECT button clicked. Starting ConnectionService");
                Intent startConnectionServiceIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ConnectionService.class);
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                context.startService(startConnectionServiceIntent);
```

In ConnectionService:

```java
public class ConnectionService extends Service {
    private BluetoothAdapter BA;
    private ConnectionStarterThread connectionStarter;
    private ConnectThread connectThread;
    private ConnectedThread connectedThread;
    private BluetoothSocket socket;
    private boolean deviceFound;

    private final BroadcastReceiver actionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                    [...]
                    deviceFound = true;
                    BA.cancelDiscovery();
                    [...]
                }
                else {
                    deviceFound = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryStartedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED.equals(action)) {

            // do something

            }
        }
    };

    private final BroadcastReceiver discoveryFinishedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {

                // do something else

            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        registerReceiver(actionFoundReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        registerReceiver(discoveryStartedReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED));
        registerReceiver(discoveryFinishedReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED));
        Log.d(Constants.TAG, "ConnectionService started");

        BA.startDiscovery();

        connectionStarter = new ConnectionStarterThread();
        connectionStarter.run();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
```

**The question is: what am I doing wrong?**

To specify - this code:

```java
connectionStarter = new ConnectionStarterThread();
connectionStarter.run();
```

is responsible for creating a `Thread` which repeatably checks if `deviceFound` variable has been set to `true` (should be handled by `actionFoundReceiver`) and if so, starts Bluetooth connection (this is done as suggested at Android Developers examples). Maybe the problem lies here?

**What I already tried:**

1. Googling the topic - people generally suggest to do it the same way as above.
2. I have Bluetooth permissions in manifest file.
3. Registered `BroadcastReceivers` as subclasses of `BroadcastReceiver` class - did not help.

Could someone help me with this issue? Is there a simplier way to do it?

Comment: +1 for a well-written and well-researched question. Welcome to SO. Looking over this, I'm wondering why you put the BT discovery into a Service at all. `startDiscovery()` is already asynchronous, so that's not really necessary. Have you confirmed that all the code -- especially the registrations -- is executed?

Comment: what in your opinion connectionStarter.run()  should do?

Comment: It should start a `while(true)` loop in which every two seconds does this:
`if (deviceFound == true) {` and executes some code if so.
I confirmed that the program does not enter `onReceive()` method of any receiver.

Comment: see Thread docs on how to start() the Thread

Comment: Sure I'll do it, but why the program does not go into `onReceive()`s?

Comment: i dont know what you are doing inside ConnectionStarterThread so i cannot say much,  but first of all start that Thread and see what happens

Comment: @pskink
Actually I don't know what other solution to start a thread you suggest. After I use start() instead of run(), it immediately goes to some kind of idle state - starts `ZygoteInit` class. Should I use runnable? 
@323go
Should I start discovery before starting the service?

Comment: `"Thread#start(): Starts the new Thread of execution. The run() method of the receiver will be called by the receiver Thread itself (and not the Thread calling start())."` this is the only method to start a new Thread